# Git rebase branch while on a different branch?

Tags: git

We have a dev and master branches, and branches generally spawn from dev, but we had a mismerge on master which included commits from dev that weren't meant to be, so we reverted; now we have another branch from dev, and we want to rebase that branch onto master so that any other dev commits/merges aren't included on master, but I don't want to switch to the branch from master to rebase...

Is it possible to rebase the branch onto master while master is checked out?

Comment: What's the problem with switching branches? If you've got uncommitted changes you're worried about losing you can just stash them first.

Comment: Agree with Matthew Strawbridge, but I'd go further and suggest just committing what you have.  That may seem to complicate things, but in fact it does the opposite.  If you are unsure about the rebase, just note down the sha1 of all the branches you might mess up.  Then (as long as everything is committed!), you can get out of trouble by checking out the relevant branch and git reset --hard <sha1>, for every branch you want to put back to where it was.  If you don't feel safe with *that*, I very strongly recommend playing with a scratch repo and reading up on the git data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a 'manual rebase' using [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Just cherry-pick each commit on your feature branch, in order. Then push your local `master` to `origin/master` and (force push) to `origin/feature`